# Get StdClass Object Property Name

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I have the following objects which I pass to a function:

```
$this->cars->car1->engine='v8';
$this->cars->car1->hp='330';

$this->cars->car2->engine='v6'
$this->cars->car1->hp='210';

handle_car($this->cars->car1);
handle_car(this->cars->car2);
```

**The function handle_car needs to find out what car it is ie whether its "car1" or "car2".**

How can I go through the property keys to see if the property is car1 or car2? I have tried using the **get_object_vars** function but it only returns the keys of 'car1' and 'car2' not those itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing property values to your function, not property names. You should pass name directly to determine it inside function properly. Remember, `$this->cars->car1` or `$this->cars->car2` are just objects, where could be anything.

Comment: So you saying its not possible to do?